# generate c# test method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, code-generation

I was just wondering, given an input file(excel,xml etc), can we generate a unit test code in c#? Consider for example, I need to validate a database. In the input excel file, i will mention which all attributes to be set, which all to retrieve, expected value etc. Also for these , i can provide the queries to run. So given these many inputs from my side, can I create a unit test case method in c# through some tool or script or another program? Sorry if this sounds dumb. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Why not? Code generation is commonly used. One possible solution might be T4. But I am on the same side as @HimBromBeere...

Answer (score 0):

A unit-test should test if your **software works correct/as expected** not that your **data is correct**. To be concise you should test the software that *imported* the data to your database. When the data *is already in* the database you can however write a validation-script or something similar which has nothing to do with a Unit-Test (however the script may be tested of course for working correctly).

You should however test if the queries provided by your software to run against the database are correct and wheather they work as expected, with both arbitrary and real-world-data.

Even when code-generation is involved you do not want to check if the process of generating the source-code works correctly (at least until you did not write your own code-generator). Simply assume the generator works as expected and **continue with the stuff you can handle yourself**.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question some time back, though not in the context of unit tests. This code that can be generated from another file/database table is called [Boilerplate Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34166766/whats-the-motivation-behind-differentiating-any-regular-code-and-boilerplate-co/34425441#34425441).

So if you ask whether this **can** be done, the answer is yes. But if you wonder whether this should be done, the answer is no. Unit tests are not ideal boilerplate code. They are mutable... On catching an edge case that you did not consider earlier you may have to add a few more tests.

Also, unit tests are often used to not just test the code but to drive code development. This method is known as Test Driven Development (abbr. TDD). It'd be a mess to "drive" your development from boilerplate tests.